# How to properly integrate "Gamestate switch"

Tags: c#, windows, menu, xna, switch-statement

I am working on a simple XNA game for school. I am trying to implement a gamestate function using a menu component which is located in a separate class. 
At this point the menu is visible and the game is seen frozen in the background, but the options(play game etc) cannot be activated.
How should I go about starting the game based on the users input?

(Load Content)

```
menuComponent = new MenuComponent(this,
            spriteBatch,
            Content.Load<SpriteFont>("menufont"),
            menuItems);
        Components.Add(menuComponent);
```

(Update)

```
switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.Menu:
                if (CurrentGameState == GameState.Menu)
                {
                    menuComponent.Visible = true;
                }

                if (CurrentGameState == GameState.Playgame)
                {
                    menuComponent.Visible = false;
                }

                break;
```